# Error while trying to configure WebDriver on google colab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The code I wrote on google colab:

```
    !pip install selenium
    !apt-get update 
    !apt install chromium-chromedriver
    from selenium import webdriver 
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

   chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')`

   wh_chrome = webdriver.chrome(chrome_options= chrome_options) # the error above happens here
```

Error trace:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-9e2933988912> in <module>
----> 1 wh_chrome = webdriver.chrome(chrome_options= chrome_options)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Solutions I tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I tried to watch some videos, but there's always some error configuring WebDriver. I have no knowledge in python, just starting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your below line:

```
wh_chrome = webdriver.chrome(chrome_options= chrome_options)
```

`webdriver.chrome` should be `webdriver.Chrome`.
So change that line of code to below:

```
wh_chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options= chrome_options)
```

After changing the code as above, `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` will be fixed. However, depending on the version of selenium you are using you may get the below deprecation warning

```
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
```

If you do get this, change your code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options

chrome_options = options.Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wh_chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```